# How to add a Course object to an array via an addCourse() method

Tags: java, arrays

I am having issues with objects and classes.

I had to define two classes:

- `Course`: a course has a code, an name and a number of credits
- `Teacher`: a teacher has a first name and last name. He can be asked his full  name.

So far so good, I got no issue with them, but I have to do next assignment which I was trying to do in the last 2 days and I could not find a proper answer:

> Extend the code of the class teacher. A teacher also has a list of courses he can teach. Add an array of Courses to the code. Also add a function `addCourse(Course aCourse)` to the code. Courses can also be removed from teachers.

I could do everyting in my way but no clue on how to create the `addCourse(Course aCourse)` method.

Find below my coding, but it must be according to the method described:

```
public class Course {

    private String courseCode;
    private String courseName;
    private String numberOfCredits;

    public Course(String courseCode, String courseName, String numberOfCredits) {
        super();
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.numberOfCredits = numberOfCredits;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(courseCode + "\t" + courseName + "\t" + numberOfCredits);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Course[] courseArray = new Course[4];

        System.out.println("Code" + "\t" + "Name" + "\t" + "Credits");

        courseArray[0] = new Course("001", "Hist", "3");
        courseArray[1] = new Course("002", "Phy", "3");
        courseArray[2] = new Course("003", "Math", "3");
        courseArray[3] = new Course("004", "Log", "3");

        for (int i = 0; i < courseArray.length; i++) {
            courseArray[i].print();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I would think he is allowed to use List structure based on the required addCourse(Course) method (it would be a bit hard to implement it with an array structure because you would need to handle resizing, and this seems to be a beginner course)

Comment: Below you can find the code that I did, but it should by using the method discribed:

Comment: @MarcoPierreFernándezBurgos I don't see a `Teacher` class defined there?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are fixed length collections of objects, so you'll need to decide how big your array should be. Let's call the length of your array `MAX_COURSES`. A more advanced solution might resize the array when required, but I get the impression this is beyond the scope of your course.

So you need to define the `Course[]` array as a field of your `Teacher` class. The syntax of array declarations is [quite easy to research](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), so I won't put that in here. Just make sure your array length is equal to `MAX_COURSES`.

Now, to add courses to the array, you need to know where to put them. To keep track of the next free position of the array, the easiest thing to do is to declare a field in your class:

```
private int numCourses = 0;
```

Now, when you add a new course, insert the course into the index specified by `numCourses`. Make sure you increment `numCourses` after you've added the course.

Finally, you ought to test to see if your array is full before you agree to insert a new course into the array, i.e. check if `numCourses` is smaller than `MAX_COURSES`. If it's not, you need to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a collection (such as a `List`) rather than an array. The code would look something like:

```
public class Teacher {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();

    public Teacher(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void addCourse(Course course) {
        courses.add(course);
    }
}
```

Based on that example, you should be able to add the `removeCourse` method yourself, and any other method you need to operate on the list of courses.

If you want to return the list as an array, you could always convert it, e.g:

```
public Course[] getCourses() {
    return courses.toArray(new Course[courses.size()]); 
}
```

If you really need to use an array for the data structure based on your assignment, something you can try when adding and removing courses, is to construct a list from the array of courses, add or remove a course from that list, the convert the list back to an array of courses.

Comment: Since this is a programming assignment, I think it's a safe bet that arrays must be used. Also, since it's an assignment, it's best if your answer describes how to produce a solution rather than just presenting the solution.

Comment: I see with ArrayList seems better and clener, I will give a try.

Comment: How should I call the method addCourse to add a course?

Comment: In your main method, you will need to create an instance of the Teacher class, let's call it teacher, and call teacher.addCourse, passing a course instance as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

There's really 3 options here.

## Option 1

If you're allowed to use `List` constructs:

```
private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();

public void addCourse(Course aCourse)
{
    if (aCourse == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    courses.add(aCourse);
}
```

## Option 2

The uses arrays, but it doesn't scale.  Assume that a teacher can only have a maximum of X courses, in my example 10:

```
// Yes, I stole Duncan's variable names

private final int MAX_COURSES = 10;

private int numCourses = 0;
private Course[] courses = new Course[MAX_COURSES]; 

public void addCourse(Course aCourse) {
    if (aCourse == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (numCourses >= courses.length)
    {
        return;
    }

    courses[numCourses] = aCourse;
    numCourses++;
}
```

## Option 3

This is identical to the previous item, but is a bit smarter in that it can resize the array... by creating a new one using the static method [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-)

```
// Yes, I stole Duncan's variable names

private final int MAX_COURSES = 10;

private int numCourses = 0;
private Course[] courses = new Course[MAX_COURSES]; 

public void addCourse(Course aCourse) {
    if (aCourse == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (numCourses >= courses.length)
    {
        int size = courses.length * 2;
        courses = Arrays.copyOf(courses, size);
    }

    courses[numCourses] = aCourse;
    numCourses++;
}
```

Comment: Note:  If your instructor dislikes multiple returns, you'll have to rewrite part of this.

Comment: Actually, some of those returns should probably throw exceptions... `IllegalArgumentException` for passing in null for example.